# Copy an image in Amazon S3 from Image URL using Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I have  an image URL (for example: http://www.myexample.come/testImage.jpg) and I would to upload this image on Amazon S3 using Django.

I'm not found a way to copy directly the resource from URL in Amazon S3 passing directly the file URL.

So, I think that i have to implement these steps in my project:

1. Download the file locally from URL http://www.myexample.come/testImage.jpg. I will have a local file testImage.jpg
2. I have to upload the local file into Amazon S3. I will have a S3 Url.
3. I have to delete the local file testImage.jpg

Is this a good way to build this feature?

Is possible to improve these steps?

I have to use this features when I receive a REST request and I have to respond passing in the response the uploaded S3 File Url... Are these steps a good way about performance?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way off the top of my head would be to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) with [io](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) from the python std lib -- this is a bit of code I used a while back, I just tested it with python 2.7.9 and it works

```
>>> requests_image('http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/_static/requests-sidebar.png')
```

and it works with the latest version of requests (2.6.0) - but I should point out that it's just a snippet, and I was in full control of the image urls being handed to the function, so there's nothing in the way of error checking (you could [use Pillow to open the image and confirm it's really a jpeg](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/upload-and-validate-image-from-url-in-django/), etc.)

```
import requests
from io import open as iopen
from urlparse import urlsplit

def requests_image(file_url):
    suffix_list = ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'tif', 'svg',]
    file_name =  urlsplit(file_url)[2].split('/')[-1]
    file_suffix = file_name.split('.')[1]
    i = requests.get(file_url)
    if file_suffix in suffix_list and i.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with iopen(file_name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(i.content)
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: After submitting my answer I felt slightly guilty that I didn't point out that the link about using Pillow actually goes to a tutorial called "Uploading And Validating An Image From An Url With Django" which is probably more in line with what you were looking for, maybe.

http://timmyomahony.com/blog/upload-and-validate-image-from-url-in-django/

github repo:  https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-blog-examples/tree/master/image_uploader